# How to get wine to launch. exe files from a click

Tags: wine, 17.10

The question's simple enough I suppose. To launch a .exe file with wine from just double-clicking the .exe file.

On Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: What happens when you double click on it?

Comment: This ^^^... Because what you're asking is actually the default behavior.

Comment: Defaults to archive manager, no option for Wine Windows Program Loader in application options, nor option presented in menu

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/3290/windows-executables-are-started-with-archive-manager..., something changed in 17.04

Comment: The problem is that Wine isn't even an option. If it was, I would have selected it and gone from there and been fine

Comment: I posted an updated answer to it, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/971547/158442

Comment: I messed around a bit and got it going - however, Browse C and the configuration options aren't coming up in the launcher